# django sends error report showing {% elif tag%} line

Tags: django

```
{% if category %}
    {% with posts=category.blogpost_set.all %}
        {% for post in posts %}
            {% include 'blog/compenent/_post.html' %}
        {% endfor %}
{% elif tag %}
    {% with posts=tag.blogpost_set.all %}
        {% for post in posts %}
            {% include 'blog/compenent/_post.html' %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endwith %}
{% endif %}
```

message :emplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag on line 20: 'elif', expected 'endwith'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Answer (score 0):

You need to end the with you started with `{% with posts=… %}` first, so:

```
{% if category %}
    {% with posts=category.blogpost_set.all %}
        {% for post in posts %}
            {% include 'blog/compenent/_post.html' %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endwith %}
{% elif tag %}
    {% with posts=tag.blogpost_set.all %}
        {% for post in posts %}
            {% include 'blog/compenent/_post.html' %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endwith %}
{% endif %}
```